Playwright (1.43.1) trace Viewer fails to render UI
I have encountered a weird issue while testing a specific page on a website. All the tests work as expected, capturing a screenshot to a file works fine, but at some point, after the page gets rendered, the UI on Trace Viewer gets distorted. Reproduces both for Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers. This is how the page looks like on Trace Viewer, a weird mix of the current page the test navigated to, and the previous page. Has anyone encountered this issue?


Please share the code and page that reproduces this as a [mcve]. Without those, there's no way to help. Thanks!

I've had similar problems. I'm relatively new to playwright and the screenshots in trace viewer look like crap. They look great in the timeline at the top, but not in the main window. Some images that should be tiny are giant, etc.

The solution to my problem was actually modifying the webpage itself. Originally it was using a few rendering functions that weren't recognized well by Playwright Trace Viewer.
